# Segregating rows on group count basis-TALEND

Tags: java, talend

I want to implement one famous scenario of Informatica. I have an source file like this:-

```
EMPNO,EMPNAME,DEPTNO
10,A,1
11,B,2
12,C,3
13,D,4
14,E,1
15,F,1
16,G,2
17,H,3
18,I,4
19,J,2
20,K,3
21,L,1
22,M,2
```

Now I want to segregate upon occurrence of DEPTNO Column.e.g:

- If Number of occurrence of any DEPTNO>3 it will go to target.for this case DEPTNO 1 & 2 occuring 4times.so they will go to 2 Target Tables.

Is any usage of tMemorizerow component here?

I have tried using tmap component but couldn't find the occurence of DEPT NO. Is it possible using tjavaflex component writing a java code?
I am able to segregate to inputflow into 4 parts inside first tmap after tfileinputdelimited. Then I am taking 4 taggregaterow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a taggregaterow
With this component you can do the equivalent of a GROUP BY in SQL.
More over you can do an operation with the group by.
You use the count function inside

In order to filter DEPTNO you need a filter in tmap

Example :
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Moreover there are some information about the taggregaterow component :
[Here](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/18.1+tAggregateRow)

Comment: Hi Theo it is useful.But can u do with my sourcefile?

Comment: Theo,one more thing.why you are using tfixedflowinput over here?I am very much new in Talend.can it be done via tfileinputdelimited?

Comment: I use fixed input un order to create a dataset for testing you need to replace them with your data. So yes you need to put you inputdelemited

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tAggregateRow and a tFilterRow in order to aggregate your source file by DEPTNO, and then filter to get a flow with only DEPNTO with nb of occurences > 3.
Then you read again the source file, and join the flows with a tMap (inner join).

A draft of components to use :

[image: A draft of components to use]

you could also simplify the job with tHash components in order to read the source only once.

Comment: Corentin How you are finding the number of occurences?

Comment: sorry didn't see the answer by @Théo Capdet , he has a more detailed answer , both answers go the same way.